# Is there a more effective way to serialize a form with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, serialization, angularjs

Is there a way to serialize function for angularjs?

my post looks like this right now.

```
$scope.signup_submit = function () {
  var formData = {
    username: $scope.username,
    full_name: $scope.full_name,
    email: $scope.email,
    password: $scope.password,
    confirm_password: $scope.confirm_password
  }

  $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/signup',
    data: formData,
  }).success(function (data) {
    if (data.status == 'success') {
      alert('all okay');
    } else {
      alert(data.msg)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: $element.serialize()?

Comment: yes did, it returns undefined function serialize

Comment: I think he meant $(element).serialize(); You will ofcourse need to have JQuery to make that happen.

Comment: hm, i thought jquery doesnt really play well with angular looks like its a mistake, i will try, thank you

Comment: At the truth, you **should NOT wrap** an Angular element in $, as it's wrapped by default if jQuery is present. If no jQuery is present, then Angular uses a small version, [the jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

Comment: @ganaraj I meant $element.serialize() - you don't need to wrap the element in a jQuery function for it to work.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This isn't how you should access form data using AngularJS. The data in your form should be bound within the scope.

So use an object, e.g. $scope.formData, which will contain all your data structure, then each of your form elements should be bound to this using ng-model.

e.g:

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/AvGKj/13/

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name">
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="formData.address">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submit = function() {   
        console.log(this.formData);
    };
}
```

When the above form is submitted $scope.formData will contain an object of your form which can then be passed in your AJAX request. e.g:

```
Object {name: "stu", address: "england"}
```

To answer your question, there is no better method to "serialize" a forms data using AngularJS.

You could however use jQuery: $element.serialize(), but if you want to use Angular properly then go with the above method.

Comment: This won't work very well when you have multiple forms on a page, e.g. as a part of an ng-repeat directive...

Comment: @Kevin look into ng-form for dynamically created forms (e.g. as a part of an ng-repeat directive)
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

Comment: I thought the question was about serializing the form.

Comment: $scope.formData is an object. The properties of the object can be altered by your interceptors or transformers. That means you will have the framework altering your object and binded back to your UI. I think that's not a desirable "feature"