# AngularJS default value for ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to make ng-models get default values, like `''`?

I have a form on which I have used jQuery's `serialize` function, and whenever a a value is not present, it will still include it in the serialized data, E.g. `{name: '', age: ''}`.

However, when I use try using posting it by using Angular's `$http` and getting the model from `$scope`, it appears as `undefined` when it is empty.

Comment: In your controller, try adding `$scope.your_model_name_here = ''`

Comment: I tried it, but that resulted in the entire model being an empty string, and not even an empty object was created. However, explicitly initializing one property at a time like in shaunhusain's answer works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply define the properties on the model in the scope in advance of using them in your view.

If you show your controller code I'll show you what you need to update to add them to the scope.

It should look something like:

In your js file that defined the app

```
angular.module("MyModule", []).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {name:""};
}]);
```

In your HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel.name"/>
```

**Note** I prefer not having global variables/functions so I'm using a different syntax provided by Angular to avoid this and to allow for minification.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, as for now.

Comment: Yeah definitely keep in mind, I'm still a bit of an Angular noob, but I've been using it with a lot of success on three projects now, one I'm currently working on is the largest so far but all the same concepts apply regardless of scale.  Just learn to make controllers, services, and directives and you can do just about anything, plus there's a pretty sizable community already it seems and lots of great components (ng-grid, google-maps, to name a couple).  Never been a jQuery guy I jumped straight from AS3/Flex so it's pretty familiar and clean.  Snags are mostly around scope updates for me.

Comment: Yes, I am definitely looking forward to using Angular in future projects, as opposed to *only* jQuery.

Comment: @shaunhusain I think a lot of Flex developers find AngularJS a comforting place to land in this HTML5 world :)

Answer (score 11):

You may also try:

```
<div ng-init="foo={}">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo.name=''"/>
</div>
```

or:

```
<input type="text" ng-init="foo.name=''"/>
```

it will present:

```
foo = { name: '', .... }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This was the best solution for my little application where building a controller isn't necessary (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use jQuery serialize.

Your form should be bound to the scope like this:

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name">
    <input type="text" name="age" ng-model="formData.age">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submit = function() {   
        $http.post('/someUrl', $scope.formData)
    };
}
```

So that in $http you can simply pass $scope.formData.

[Is there a more effective way to serialize a form with angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877212/is-there-a-more-effective-way-to-serialize-a-form-with-angularjs/15884218#15884218)

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. However, the main problem is that it will remain an empty object (`{}`), and will not care about undefined values when you say `$scope.formData`. What I need is something that ensures the empty values are considered.

Comment: Oh I see. Well in that case define the object on your scope like this: $scope.formData = {'name':null, 'age':null};

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you don't know if the value is set or not. That's what defaults are for.

I use this when I need to make sure a variable has some value. You can set it in your controller

```
$scope.possiblyEmptyVariable = $scope.possiblyEmptyVariable || "default value";
```

Works great without Angular as well

```
// some object that may or may not have a property 'x' set
var data = {};

// Set default value of "default"
// carefull, values like 'null', false, 0 will still fall to defaults
data.x = data.x || "default";

// Set default value of "default"
// this will not fall to defaults on values like 'null', false, 0
data.x = !"x" in data || "default";
```

If you need to set a bunch of values, use angular.extend or jQuery.extend

```
data.z = "value already set";
var defaults = { x: "default", y: 1, z: "default" };
var newData = angular.extend({}, defaults, data);
// { x: "default, y: 1, z: "value already set" }
```

Hope that helps