# Is there a way to set the initial value of a checkbox to false?

Tags: angularjs

I have:

```
<input ng-model="answer.response" type="checkbox" />
```

When data is fetched from the server there will initially be no value for answer.response.

Is there a way I can make this default to false?

Comment: Merge the defaults into the fetched (property-less) model?

Comment: Can you explain how I could do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS default value for ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414654/angularjs-default-value-for-ng-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is bound to the model *answer.response*.

If you want to default it to false, then set answer.response to false in your controller.

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.answer = { response: false };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input ng-model="answer.response" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Initalization code belongs in the controller. [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is only appropriate for aliasing special properties of ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2):

check this out: use ng-init

```
<div ng-init="options={};options.selected=false">
    <input type="checkbox" 
        ng-checked="options.selected"
        ng-model="options.selected"/>
</div>
```