# Send ajax request in angularjs with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have form like below. Here I have taken value of each element and send it to server via ajax call. Is their any easy way to send request to server using all values in form ?? I am a newbie please help. My form has a lot of element its very hard to take value of all element, is their any alternative method?

```
<div ng-app="Myapp">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="orderFormController">
        Item1<input type="text" name="item1"  ng-model='item1'><p></p>
        Item2 <input type="text" name="item2"  ng-model='item2'><p></p>
        Item3 <input type="text" name="item3"  ng-model='item3'><p></p>
         Item4 <input type="text" name="item4"  ng-model='item4'><p></p>
        Item5 <input type="text" name="item5"  ng-model='item5'><p></p>
        <button type="button"  ng-click='saveAll()' >SAVE ORDER</button>
    </div>    
    <script>
        Myapp.controller('orderFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

                 var data = {};
                $scope.saveAll = function () {
                    data = {'item1': $scope.item1,'item2': $scope.item2,'item3': $scope.item3,'item4': $scope.item4}
                    $http.post("order/save/", data
                        ).success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
                    if (res == 'success')
                    {
                        $scope.message = res;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.message = res;
                    }
                }).error(function (res, status) { 
                    $scope.message = res;
                });
                }

            }]);

    </script>
```

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877212/is-there-a-more-effective-way-to-serialize-a-form-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Place a parent object on the scope and wire your properties to it.  The parent object is then what you send.

```
<div ng-app="Myapp">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="orderFormController">
        Item1<input type="text" name="item1"  ng-model='data.item1'><p></p>
        Item2 <input type="text" name="item2"  ng-model='data.item2'><p></p>
        Item3 <input type="text" name="item3"  ng-model='data.item3'><p></p>
         Item4 <input type="text" name="item4"  ng-model='data.item4'><p></p>
        Item5 <input type="text" name="item5"  ng-model='data.item5'><p></p>
        <button type="button"  ng-click='saveAll()' >SAVE ORDER</button>
    </div>    
    <script>
        Myapp.controller('orderFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

                 var data = {};
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.saveAll = function () {
                    $http.post("order/save/", data
                        ).success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
                    if (res == 'success')
                    {
                        $scope.message = res;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.message = res;
                    }
                }).error(function (res, status) { 
                    $scope.message = res;
                });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to just send your model to the server, using `$resource` (for REST)

```
<div ng-controller="orderFormController">
    Item1
    <input type="text" name="item1" ng-model='item.item1'><p></p>
    Item2 
    <input type="text" name="item2" ng-model='item.item2'><p></p>
    Item3 
    <input type="text" name="item3" ng-model='item.item3'><p></p>
    Item4 
    <input type="text" name="item4" ng-model='item.item4'><p></p>
    Item5 
    <input type="text" name="item5" ng-model='item.item5'><p></p>

    <button type="button"  ng-click='saveAll()' >SAVE ORDER</button>
</div>  

$scope.item.$save(function(data) {

});
```

`$item` is a angularjs resource