# How can I pass my viewmodel data from my view to my controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Currently, my view looks something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {<form ng-controller="MyController">
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { ng_model = "user.firstName" }) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { ng_model = "user.lastName" })) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="addUser()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    }
```

My Controller (on ASP.NET MVC side):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UsersViM usersVM)
{
  //Sets the model equal to viewmodel 
  //Saves the name in session and redirects to previous view with new list of names. 
}
```

I am wondering, what data should I be passing from my view to my controller? That is, how do I pass my model from my view to my controller? How do I set that up in angular?

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    var data = {
        //user.firstname, user.lastname but how does angular know what user is? 
        //User is defined as the Model on the ASP.NET MVC side. 
    };

    $http
        .post('Home/Create', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        })
        .errors(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
};
```

Comment: You can `serialize` the `form` and sent it as data. The `serialize object` will be type of Model of your View. So it View Model is `UsersViewModel` then it will be serialized as `UsersViewModel` at `CreateUser`

Comment: How can I serialize the form data in js/angular?

Comment: `var data = {FirstName:'John', LastName: 'Terry'};`

Comment: Well I mean, above I have the user enter the first and last name, so I can't assign it like that. I need to pass in the textbox parameter to the data. How do I serialize that?

Comment: Not sure about in angular. but through js you can do something like `var data = $("form").serialize()`.

Comment: Check it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877212/is-there-a-more-effective-way-to-serialize-a-form-with-angularjs) link help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.addUser = function () {
                $http
                    .post('Home/CreateUser', usersViewModel)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        successFn();
                    })
                    .errors(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        errorFn();
                    });
            };
```

Your back-end model fields should be same as like front-end model fields so that the mapping will not generate an error.

Comment: how does it know about usersViewModel? It doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you have defined you scope as mentioned below then define the user property so that angular can bind it with ng-model properties.

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.user= {};

    $scope.addUser= function() {   
        console.log(this.user);
        ......
    };
}
```

When the above form is submitted $scope.addUser will contain an object of your form which can then be passed in your http post request. e.g:

```
Object {firstName: "Test First Name", lastName: "Test Last Name"}
```